# ggplot2: facet_wrap failure for multi-layered plots with two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a multi-faceted plot with free scaling using `ggplot2`. By design, `facet_grid`, cannot achieve what I need. And `facet_wrap` fails with a cryptic error. Could you please tell me, do you have any suggestions on how to fix the error? A reproducible example is given below.

Let's create sample data:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(modelr)

d1 <- tibble(
  x = 1:100,
  y = 1:100 + rnorm(10),
  z = y ^ 2,
  dataset_name = "d1"
)

d2 <- tibble(
  x = 1:1000,
  y = 1:1000 + rnorm(10),
  z = y ^ 2,
  dataset_name = "d2"
)

#these data will be used for the 1st layer
actuals <- bind_rows(d1, d2)

#these data will be used for the 2nd layer
predictions <- bind_rows(
  d1 %>% gather_predictions(
    "m1" = lm(y ~ x, data = d1),
    "m2" = lm(y ~ x + z, data = d1),
    .pred = "y"
  ),
  d2 %>% gather_predictions(
    "m1" = lm(y ~ x, data = d2),
    "m2" = lm(y ~ x + z, data = d2),
    .pred = "y"
  )
)
```

`facet_grid` generated the required graphs:

[image: the figure])

But it cannot (by design) scale the x-axis:

```
ggplot(actuals, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = predictions, colour = "red") +
  facet_grid(dataset_name ~ model, scales = "free")
```

If I want to plot the data only for one dataset (namely, `predictions`), it works as expected and I get 4 facets:

[image: img]

```
ggplot(predictions, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ model + dataset_name, scales = "free")
```

However, if I try to combine `actuals` and `predictions` as follows:

```
ggplot(actuals, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = predictions, colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap( ~ model + dataset_name, scales = "free")
```

Then things fall apart with the following error: `Error in gList(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1, just = "centre",  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have a `model` variable in `actuals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a single variable with the interaction of `model` and `dataset_name`.

```
# these two blocks of code are equivalent

library(magrittr)
predictions %<>% mutate(mod_dn = interaction(model, dataset_name))
```

and

```
predictions <- predictions %>% 
  mutate(mod_dn = interaction(model, dataset_name))
```

Now, this poses a problem for `facet_wrap`, since `mod_dn` does not exist there.  So we need to merge the two datasets together.  Using `tidyverse`, we can do this with `left_join`, but we need to be careful about what we join by, and then adjust the `ggplot` call accordingly:

```
all_data <- left_join(
  actuals,
  predictions,
  by = c("x", "dataset_name"),
  suffix = c(".actual", ".pred")
)

all_data %>%
ggplot(aes(x, y.actual)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = y.pred), colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap( ~ mod_dn, scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "y")
```

Comment: Thank you @Melissa! Note that if I tweaked your solution correctly, it breaks the actual data rendering. Essentially, all four plots show a union of `d1` and `d2` data on both graphs, see this [image](https://pasteboard.co/HoYeDp6.png).

Comment: good catch - I fixed the issue and it should perform as desired now.  The `%<>%` notation requires the `magrittr` package, but it's identical in effect to your tweak.

Comment: You can skip the step of getting an interaction term and just join the two data frames, then use `facet_wrap(~ model + dataset_name)`. As far as I can tell, the only difference is whether the strip labels are single (e.g. "m1.d1") or stacked double (e.g. "m1" on top, "d1" below). That said, the single strip labels  probably look cleaner for many purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help! It seems that a more straightforward solution (even though it will alter the original question), would be to tweak the `predictions` as follows:

```
predictions <- bind_rows(
  d1 %>% gather_predictions(
    "m1" = lm(y ~ x, data = d1),
    "m2" = lm(y ~ x + z, data = d1),
    .pred = "y.pred"
  ),
  d2 %>% gather_predictions(
    "m1" = lm(y ~ x, data = d2),
    "m2" = lm(y ~ x + z, data = d2),
    .pred = "y.pred"
  )
)
```

Then we can do the plotting without resorting to joins:

```
ggplot(predictions, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y.pred), colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap( ~ model + dataset_name, scales = "free")
```

This renders the [desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkYLU.png).